# Проблемы с htaccess! Не работают .css файлы!

Tags: .htaccess, apache, пути

CSS-стили не работают при двух нижеописанных htaccessах.

Рут-папка проекта (тут 1ый htaccess)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка app
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка web (тут 2ой htaccess)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется 2 htaccess. Они нужны для редиректа любого пути в строке браузера на index.php. Он является фронт-контроллером в моём проекте.

1ый - редирект на папку РутПапка/app/web/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2ой - редирект на index.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь в файле в папке view обратиться к стилям в папке РутПапка/app/design/styles/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=<?= "http://РутПапка/app/design/styles/" . $config['cssfile'] . ".css"?>>
```

Вроде бы все и хорошо, файл.css работает на нужной странице, но только без htaccess! Пробовал ставить любые пути - относительные, абсолютные, толку ноль.

Моё предположение:

Как я понимаю апач не может обработать этот файл так как редирект htaccesов кидает его на РутПапка/app/web/index.php.

Что делать? Мне обязательно нужен редирект путей на index.php, но и при том что бы CSS-стили подключались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я удалил 2ой htaccess который лежал в папке с фронт-контроллером, а первому дал правила. Все запросы идут на фронт-контроллер + заработали стили.

```html
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

# Start to Rewrite
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(css|fonts|img|js)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /app/design/%1%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?app/web/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|fonts|img|js)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /app/web/index.php [NC,L]
```